# How to compare int and list of int in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Compare a list of int with an int:

```
a = [-1,-1,0,2]
a > 1
```

I want to get a result looks like:

```
[False,False,False,True]
```

How can I do this in Python3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In native Python:

```
a = [-1,-1,0,2]
bools = [x > 1 for x in a]

>>> [False, False, False, True]
```

In numpy you can use the simpler syntax like in your example though (this will also be noticeably faster if you have millions of values rather than just four):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([-1,-1,0,2])
bools = a > 1

>>> array([False, False, False,  True])
```

Answer (score 1):

Comprehension will do it:

```
[i > 1 for i in a]
```

Otherwise you can use `numpy`:

```
a = np.array([-1,-1,0,2])
a > 1
#[False False False  True]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using [list comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

```
source_arr = [-1,-1,0,2]
condition = 1
print([item > condition for item in source_arr]) #--> [False, False, False, True]
```

Answer (score 1):

In a simpler form factor

```
a = [-1,-1,0,2]
b = []
for x in a:
    b.append(x>1)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-**

```
a = [-1,-1,0,2]
ls = [True if x>1 else False for x in a]
print(ls)
```

**Output:-**

```
[False, False, False, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `lambda` with `map`

**Demo:**

```
a = [-1,-1,0,2]
print(list(map(lambda x: x > 1, a)))
```

**Output:**

```
[False, False, False, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>> a = [-1,-1,0,2]
>> b = 1
>> [x > b for x in a]
```